# Invalid Content-Type 'multipart/; boundary

Tags: perl, email, download, email-attachments, mime

I am using Perl and Email::MIME to access an email account via IMAP.  When I try to download the attachment, I get this error:

> Invalid Content-Type 'multipart/;
>   boundary="===============6113972194662902815=="' at
>   /path/to/class/Reader.pm line 99.

Here is my code:

```
my $env = $self->env();
my $imap = $self->imap();
my $logger = $self->logger();

my ($OUT, $out_file);

# parse attachment
my $message_string = $imap->message_string($imap_id);

Email::MIME->new($message_string)->walk_parts(sub {

    my ($part) = @_;

    if ($part->content_type =~ /octet\-stream/) {
        ($OUT, $out_file) = tempfile();
        binmode $OUT;

        print $OUT $part->body;
        close $OUT;

        $logger->info("downloaded attached report: [$out_file]");
    }

});
```

Here is the end of the dump of the $part:

```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=

--===============6113972194662902815==--
",
    ct           => {
        attributes => {
            charset => "us-ascii"
        },
        composite  => "plain",
        discrete   => "text",
        subtype    => "plain",
        type       => "text"
    },
    encode_check => 1,
    header       => Email::MIME::Header,
    mycrlf       => "
",
         parts        => []
    }
}
```

I have tried several different methods of downloading this file and I keep getting that error.  Let me know if there are any questoins

Comment: The content type of the message is `multipart/; boundary="..."`, but it should be `multipart/SOMETHING; boundary="..."` (probably `multipart/mixed; boundary="..."`).

Comment: Tip: `my ($OUT, $out_file);` is incorrectly located. It should be inside the `if`. (`my ($OUT, $out_file) = tempfile();`)

Comment: Tip: No need to escape `-` in regex patterns (unless it's in a character class (`[...]`)).

Comment: @ikegami you were correct.  I changed the message string from multipart/; boundary= to multipart/mixed; boundary= and it worked!